# ubuntu 12.04 LTS vs 13.04? which is faster and more stable?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, speed, ubuntu-13.04

I have an Asus U36SG with i5, 4GB RAM, nVidia 610M 1GB video with 12.04 LTS installed.

Somethimes the sistem crashes when I browse in Chromium with more than ~50 tabs. I wonder if 13.04 is faster or not. Is it more stable than 12.04 LTS?

Thanks

Comment: Every system will crash sooner or later if you open 50 tabs in a browser.

Answer (score 2):

Well with ~50 tabs open it's not a surprise your system crashes :P And No 13.04 isn't more stable than 12.04 LTS.

My Opinion: LTS stands for "Long Term Support" And so should be more stable than 13.04. The other thing is, ubuntu 13.04 is a newer release of Ubuntu, so it has newer applications in its repository, as well as newer libraries. It also has a newer version of Unity.

The downside of using a non-LTS release is that they are not as heavily tested by Ubuntu, they have a shorter support lifetime, and they are not as well supported by third parties.

So 13.04 my be faster because of the newer applications but can be buggy.

I stayed on 12.04 LTS and am waiting for the new 14.04 LTS release.

Check here for more info regarding LTS: [LTS is an abbreviation for “Long Term Support”](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS)

Also check this post: [install 13.04 or stay with 12.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/284239/install-13-04-or-stay-with-12-04-lts)